# Maximum Collinear points in a plane

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, geometry

`N` points are given as input.

Let's say `(x1,y1), (x2,y2)... (xn,yn)`.

Is there a non-combinatorial solution to find the maximum number of collinear points? Can they be arranged in a fancy data structure that would help this computation?

Comment: Take a look at this question and its answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179581/what-is-the-most-efficient-algorithm-to-find-a-straight-line-that-goes-through-mo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For each point i, find the slope to every other point j and
look for duplicates. Duplicates can be found by sorting the slopes and
comparing adjacent values. Point i is collinear with the points in
each set of duplicates. Keep track of the maximal set as you go.

For each i, you have n-1 slopes to calculate and sort and compare.
Therefore, using a (n log n) sorting, the complexity of the algorithm is
O(n^2 log n).

Comment: Pairs of points might have the same slope but be parallel rather than collinear. You need to look at the y-intercept as well as the slope.

Comment: The slopes are relative to the point i currently being investigated. So there is no possibility for parallel lines.

Comment: Hi kotlinski,
Can u plz add some sample code? I'm facing problem in finding duplicate lines. So my result is getting multiplied by number of duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Read through discussion on this question [here](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?interview.11.576927.12) on

Answer (score 0):

Following could be one way to solve it:
1) Find all the slopes selecting C(n,2) pairs
2) Bin these slopes into multiple buckets.
3) Within these buckets find independent lines (as they might contain family of parallel lines)
4) Establish the longest line segment

More concretely:
1) Perform (n-1) * (n-1) calculations to find so many slopes. A map could be used to save these points with slopes as keys. The value in the map could be a represented using a Set. The Set could contain an object representing two points. Something like this:
{slope1: [(p1, p2), (p1, p3), (p1, p2), (p4, p5)]}
{slope2: ....}

2) Now, within each set of points find independent lines. I believe iterating over each point in the set we can arrive at this. For example
while visiting (p1, p2), (p1, p3), (p1, p2), (p4, p5) we can divide this into n-Sets which form collinear points. Set could start with:
[p1, p2], when we encounter next pair (p1, p3), we check if either of them are already in the current running set. If at least one of them are then we add the new points to this set, otherwise create a new set. After iterating over all the points in this set of points we will have the following two sets, representing 2 independent line segments:
[p1, p2, p3]
[p4, p5]
Size of these could now be used to establish the longest line segment we find

Complexity wise, it should be O((n-1)*(n-1) + n) ~ O(n^2). Assuming looking up objects in Set is O(1)