# Find a line passing the maximum number of points

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-theory

I found a Google Interview question on [CareerCup](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=56605)

> Given a 2D plane, suppose that there are around 6000 points on it. Find a line which passes the most number of points.

Many answers there say this question is hard and involving some kind of special algorithms.

But my view is different and maybe I am wrong.

**Here is my thinking:**

First I will give a axis system to the 2D plane. Hence, every point will have its unique x and y, i.e., `{x, y}`. For simplicity, we can put the axis system's `{0, 0}` as the left bottom of the whole plane and therefore every x and y are bigger than 0.

Then I have a theory:

If several points are on the same line, then it must be in one of the following 3 cases:

1. their **`x`** values are the same
2. their **`y`** values are the same
3. their **`x/y`** or **`y/x`** values are the same. But `x/y` case is the same as `y/x` case, so let's just focus on **`x/y`**.

Then I will have 3 hashtables.

1. The first one (`hashtable-x`) is with key of `x`, the value is the list of points which have the same `x`;
2. the second one (`hashtable-y`) is with the key of `y` and the value is the list of points which have the same `y`;
3. the last one (`hashtable-x-y`) is with the key of `x/y` and the value is the list of points which have the same `x/y`;

Then I scan the whole 6000 points, for each point, I will get its `x` from `hashtable-x`, and put the point into the value (a list) of that slot; then I will do similar things to `hashtable-y` and `hashtable-x-y`.

Finally, i will scan all lists in the 3 hashtables and find the longest list will contains the points of the desired line.

How do you think of my algorithm?

---

Ok, here is the duplicate, sorry that I didn't find that question before.

[What is the most efficient algorithm to find a straight line that goes through most points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179581/what-is-the-most-efficient-algorithm-to-find-a-straight-line-that-goes-through-m)

Comment: Considering the `x/y` ratio will only consider lines that originate in `{0, 0}`. Imagine all points are on the line where `y = x + 1` they will all have another `x`, another `y` and another `x/y`.

Comment: @Nobody Yeah, you are right. I need to think about that more deeply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm won't work as stated. Consider many points fall on the line y=2x + 1, meaning that you get (1,3),(2,5), (3,7), (4,9), and (5,11).

I don't think you're expected to solve this unless you have a graduate level course in computational geometry. The deal is to convert all the points to lines in the dual space, using point-line duality and find the point at which most lines intersect. Naively you can do this in O(n^2) by going through every pair of lines and evaluating where they intersect in analytic form. I also think you can do O(n log n) by using plane sweep style algorithms but I'm not sure of the details.

Comment: thanks. What do you mean by `convert all the points to lines in the dual space`? How to do it exactly?

Comment: For every point (x,y) and you say y = ax + b. And solve b = -xa + y, and that is a line in dual A-B space. You do that for every point and intersect lines.

Comment: do you mean that a line is in the form of `y = ax+b` provided `a` and `b` are known? How about @tskuzzy's answer?

Comment: No, b = -xa + y where x and y are known, this is a line in the a-b axis. His solution is a O(n^3) solution, impractical for 6000 points.

Comment: @carlosdc: nowadays I don't think an O(N^3) solution should be considered in principle impractical for 6000 elements. Looping 2e11 times may just take a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the number of points is greater than or equal to 2 here in my answer (zero and one point are trivial cases).

First notice that any such line must pass through at least two of the points. So we can construct a solution as follows:

```
for each pair of points p1,p2
    find equation of the line l passing through p1,p2

    for each point p3 not p1 or p2
        if p3 lies on l
            counter[l]++

return argmax(counter)
```

Comment: This is a O(N^3) approach, right?

Comment: Choosing each pair is closer to O(n^2) (technically length of nCr) and for each pair we are running against all other items (O(n)), so I think it is of order O(N^3)