# How to determine the max number of points on the same line?

Tags: c, algorithm

Given: a lot of points each with a unique coordinate (x<sub>i</sub>,y<sub>i</sub>)

Output: Max number of points on the same line

This is my method:

```
for i=1..n
    for j=i..n
        get the line determined by point[i] and point[j]
        for k=1..n
            check if point[k] is on this line
```

But it seems this method takes too much time and always exceeds the time limit on the OJ system.

Comment: can u please post ur code in a formatted manner? exact code which u are using currently would be a plus

Comment: @mihirj I'm really sorry, I didn't find a way to add linebreaks in my code.

Comment: @CDT: How many points are there? It is possible to guess the expected complexity from it.

Comment: You could speed up your algorithm by proper `for` ranges: `i` is okay, `j` should be `i+1..n`, `k` should be `j+1..n`.

Comment: a little bit different but maybe this question helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932958/find-a-line-passing-the-maximum-number-of-points

Comment: @Amadan: It will still be O(n^3), though. Assuming the problem setter is good enough, it will still time out.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I am aware. It's still a better O(n^3); and it points out a problem in code as posted. I was not offering a better solution (for which I'd've created an answer), just fixing OP's.

Comment: @ibrahim: This is the good one to close this question as dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179581/what-is-the-most-efficient-algorithm-to-find-a-straight-line-that-goes-through-m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iterate each point, calculate the polar angle for each other point, sort the polar angle

this cost O(n^2*lgn)

Comment: for polar angle calculation you should use `center`(normalization) coordinates. What coordinates the OP should use?

Comment: the center should be the iterated point in the outter most "for loop"

Comment: @Amadan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676719/calculating-the-angle-between-the-line-defined-by-two-points

Comment: Thanks a lot! This should get over the time limit~

Comment: @songlj Why sort the polar angles? Can't we loop through the list and check the count of the most frequent angle? Giving cost O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

I have not implemented this, but you might be able to do it in O(n).

- Use a hashmap to store the points by their polar angles: `Map<Double,List<Point>>`, where `Double` is the angle
- Then iterate the map, tracking the `List<Point>` with the max length. That list would contain the result.

Play with that. It looks like it should work.