# Given n points on a 2D plane, find the maximum number of points that lie on the same straight line

Tags: performance, refactoring, time-complexity, computational-geometry

Below is the solution I am trying to implement

```
/**
 * Definition for a point.
 * class Point {
 *     int x;
 *     int y;
 *     Point() { x = 0; y = 0; }
 *     Point(int a, int b) { x = a; y = b; }
 * }
 */
 public class Solution {
    public int maxPoints(Point[] points) {
    int max=0;
    if(points.length==1)
        return 1;
     for(int i=0;i<points.length;i++){
         for(int j=0;j<points.length;j++){
         if((points[i].x!=points[j].x)||(points[i].y!=points[j].y)){
         int coll=get_collinear(points[i].x,points[i].y,points[j].x,points[j].y,points);
                  if(coll>max)
                    max=coll;
                }
                else{

                    **Case where I am suffering**

                }
           }
        }
  return max;
}
public int get_collinear(int x1,int y1,int x2, int y2,Point[] points)
{
    int c=0;
    for(int i=0;i<points.length;i++){
        int k1=x1-points[i].x;
        int l1=y1-points[i].y;
        int k2=x2-points[i].x;
        int l2=y2-points[i].y;
        if((k1*l2-k2*l1)==0)
            c++;
    }
    return c;
}
}
```

It runs at O(n^3). What I am basically doing is running two loops comparing various points in the 2d plane. And then taking 2 points I send these 2 points to the get_collinear method which hits the line formed by these 2 points with all the elements of the array to check if the 3 points are collinear. I know this is a brute force method. However in case where the input is[(0,0),(0,0)] my result fails. The  else loop is where I have to add a condition to figure out such cases. Can someone help me with the solution to that. And does there exist a better solution to this problem at better run time. I can't think of any.

Comment: Couldn't you just setup a hash table of all of the non-unique points? Say you have three points {(0,0),(0,0),(0,0)}, you can let c+=3 instead of c++ in your get_collinear method

Comment: Also, you can reduce your algorithm to O(N^2).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179581/what-is-the-most-efficient-algorithm-to-find-a-straight-line-that-goes-through-m

Comment: In the above link how does finding dx/dy alone prove collinearity? Don't we need the y intercept too? I can't figure how it is O(n^2).

Comment: If you map every pair of points to `y intercept` plus `direction`, then all pair of points on the same line fall in the same bin. So that's O(n^2). But bear in mind rounding differences can be an issue if you calculate direction as a float (you could take the pair of `dx` and `dy` divided by `gcd` for accuracy).

Comment: I would use dir=atanxy(dx,dy) (or atan2(dx,dy) if you like) instead of dx/dy its a bit slover but more precise. remove duplicity points, test dir only (if dir not match than they are not colinear) and after filtering out bad lines/points check if lines are not shifted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**BTW** complexity is indeed `O(n^3)` to lower that you need to:

1. **sort the points somehow**

   by `x` and or `y` in ascending or descending order. Also use of polar coordinates can help sometimes
2. **use divide at impera (divide and conquer) algorithms**

   usually for planar geometry algorithms is good idea to divide area to **quadrants** and **sub-quadrants** but these algorithms are hard to code on vector graphics
3. **Also there is one other speedup possibility**

   check against all possible directions (limited number of them for example to `360` angles only) which leads to `O(n^2)`. Then compute results which is still `O(m^3)` where `m` is the subset of points per the tested direction.

**Ok here is something basic I coded in C++ for example:**

```cpp
void points_on_line()   
    {
    const int dirs =360;            // num of directions (accuracy)
    double mdir=double(dirs)/M_PI;  // conversion from angle to code
    double pacc=0.01;               // position acc <0,1>
    double lmin=0.05;               // min line size acc <0,1>
    double lmax=0.25;               // max line size acc <0,1>
    double pacc2,lmin2,lmax2;

    int n,ia,ib;
    double x0,x1,y0,y1;
    struct _lin
        {
        int dir;        // dir code <0,dirs>
        double ang;     // dir [rad] <0,M_PI>
        double dx,dy;   // dir unit vector
        int i0,i1;      // index of points
        } *lin;
    glview2D::_pnt *a,*b;
    glview2D::_lin q;
    _lin l;
    // prepare buffers
    n=view.pnt.num;     // n=number of points
    n=((n*n)-n)>>1;     // n=max number of lines
    lin=new _lin[n]; n=0;
    if (lin==NULL) return;
    // precompute size of area and update accuracy constants ~O(N)
    for (a=view.pnt.dat,ia=0;ia<view.pnt.num;ia++,a++)
        {
        if (!ia)
            {
            x0=a->p[0]; y0=a->p[1];
            x1=a->p[0]; y1=a->p[1];
            }
        if (x0>a->p[0]) x0=a->p[0];
        if (x1<a->p[0]) x1=a->p[0];
        if (y0>a->p[1]) y0=a->p[1];
        if (y1<a->p[1]) y1=a->p[1];
        }
    x1-=x0; y1-=y0; if (x1>y1) x1=y1;
    pacc*=x1; pacc2=pacc*pacc;
    lmin*=x1; lmin2=lmin*lmin;
    lmax*=x1; lmax2=lmax*lmax;
    // precompute lines ~O((N^2)/2)
    for (a=view.pnt.dat,ia=0;ia<view.pnt.num;ia++,a++)
     for (b=a+1,ib=ia+1;ib<view.pnt.num;ib++,b++)
        {
        l.i0=ia;
        l.i1=ib;
        x0=b->p[0]-a->p[0];
        y0=b->p[1]-a->p[1];
        x1=(x0*x0)+(y0*y0);
        if (x1<=lmin2) continue;        // ignore too small lines
        if (x1>=lmax2) continue;        // ignore too big lines
        l.ang=atanxy(x0,y0);
        if (l.ang>M_PI) l.ang-=M_PI;    // 180 deg is enough lines goes both ways ...
        l.dx=cos(l.ang);
        l.dy=sin(l.ang);
        l.dir=double(l.ang*mdir);
        lin[n]=l; n++;
//      q.p0=*a; q.p1=*b; view.lin.add(q);  // just visualise used lines for testing
        }

    // test directions
    int cnt,cntmax=0;
    double t;
    for (ia=0;ia<n;ia++)
        {
        cnt=1;
        for (ib=ia+1;ib<n;ib++)
         if (lin[ia].dir==lin[ib].dir)
            {
            a=&view.pnt[lin[ia].i0];
            if (lin[ia].i0!=lin[ib].i0)
                 b=&view.pnt[lin[ib].i0];
            else b=&view.pnt[lin[ib].i1];
            x0=b->p[0]-a->p[0]; x0*=x0;
            y0=b->p[1]-a->p[1]; y0*=y0;
            t=sqrt(x0+y0);
            x0=a->p[0]+(t*lin[ia].dx)-b->p[0]; x0*=x0;
            y0=a->p[1]+(t*lin[ia].dy)-b->p[1]; y0*=y0;
            t=x0+y0;
            if (fabs(t)<=pacc2) cnt++;
            }
        if (cntmax<cnt)                         // if more points on single line found
            {
            cntmax=cnt;                         // update point count
            q.p0=view.pnt[lin[ia].i0];          // copy start/end point
            q.p1=q.p0;
            q.p0.p[0]-=500.0*lin[ia].dx;    // and set result line as very big (infinite) line
            q.p0.p[1]-=500.0*lin[ia].dy;
            q.p1.p[0]+=500.0*lin[ia].dx;
            q.p1.p[1]+=500.0*lin[ia].dy;
            }
        }
    if (cntmax) view.lin.add(q);

    view.redraw=true;
    delete lin;
//  Caption=n;      // just to see how many lines actualy survive the filtering
    }
```

It is from my geometry engine so here is some stuff explained:

`glview2D::_pnt`

`view.pnt[]` are input **2D** points (I feed random points around random line + random noise points)

`view.pnt.num` is number of points

`glview2D::_lin`

`view.lin[]` are output lines (just one line is used)

**accuracy**

Play with `pacc,lmin,lmax` constants to change the behavior and computation speed. Change `dirs` to change direction accuracy and computation speed

Complexity estimation is not possible due to big dependency on input data
But for my random test points are the runtimes like this:

```
[   0.056 ms]Genere  100 random 2D points
[ 151.839 ms]Compute 100 points on line1 (unoptimized brute force O(N^3))
[   4.385 ms]Compute 100 points on line2 (optimized direction check)

[   0.096 ms] Genere  200 random 2D points
[1041.676 ms] Compute 200 points on line1
[  39.561 ms] Compute 200 points on line2

[   0.440 ms] Genere  1000 random 2D points
[29061.54 ms] Compute 1000 points on line2
```

[image: 1000 points some near line]