# Linear equation or gradient (m) prediction from many pixels

Tags: algorithm, graphics, pixel, bresenham

I'm starting to learn Bresenham algorithm, which is plotting discrete coordinate points along the line patch.

But, is there any method to predict the linear equation or gradient (m) from many pixels? (reverse-bresenham algorithm)

Comment: the keyword is "line fitting"

Comment: and "regression" look here  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20888844/2521214